# Area 51 login failure with HTTPS Everywhere

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, login, stack-exchange-openid

I could not log in to Area 51 in Chrome 62 under Linux. After entering my credentials and authenticating to my OpenID provider ([Stack Exchange](https://openid.stackexchange.com/)), I was redirected back to `https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/authenticate/?s=…` and not logged in. (Full URL and error message omitted because it contains PII, available to staff in case there's something you can't find in your logs.)

[image: partial screenshot]

I was already logged in on other SE sites. This turned out to be due to HTTPS Everywhere: after I disabled the extension and visited http://area51.stackexchange.com/, I was logged in automatically. Once I was logged in, I turned HTTPS Everywhere back on and the site worked.

Given that [HTTPS support on Area 51 is supposed to be complete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time), there shouldn't have been any HTTP request at any point, therefore this is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). It had been [previously reported](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276702/cannot-log-into-area-51-with-openid), but at the time HTTPS support was not officially supported so it wasn't a bug.

Comment: They [don't officially support](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284856/323179) HTTPS Everywhere though.

Comment: @Laurel that's pre https migration (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292058/network-wide-https-its-time)

Comment: @Laurel That answer is from before there was official HTTPS support (let alone HTTPS Everywhere). Now, HTTPS is supposed to be fully supported. Since I accessed https://area51.stackexchange.com/, no HTTP request should have been made at all, so HE shouldn't have kicked in.

Comment: Can reproduce. Was about to post a duplicate question but thought to search first. :-)

Comment: Reproduced (firefox 59.0.1 with HTTPS Everywhere). This is supposed to be after the HTTPS migration too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We changed the way Area51 login works a few months ago to route through meta.stackexchange.com as part of several steps to unify our login system. As a result of that, this is now fixed. We'll be enforcing HTTPS on Area 51 shortly as well.