# Forced to login to Meta to be able to login to Area51

Tags: discussion, area-51, login

I was forced to login to Meta Stack Exchange to be able to login to Area51.
Is this expected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is by design and therefore expected. The same is true for logging in to https://chat.stackexchange.com. I quote [Nick Craver](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) (Architecture Lead) from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322101/158100)

> We changed the way Area51 login works a few months ago to route through meta.stackexchange.com as part of several steps to unify our login system

*A few months ago* would have been October 2018 or so but I can't find the actual date or announcement on that. Maybe Nick or Adam can edit that in if they stumble on this answer.